# Why is the model getting 100% accuracy for SVM, Random-forest Classifier and Logistic Regression?

Tags: python, machine-learning, svm, random-forest

> I'm using an existing disease prediction model to build a chatbot. While I was referring to the model I realized that it has an accuracy of 100%. I'm not quite sure how and why the accuracy is 100%. I've attached herewith the link to the code I'm referring to - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/disease-prediction-using-machine-learning/

> I would be glad if someone could give me some insight on how the accuracy is 100%. Below is the code

```
from cgi import test
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import mode
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, cross_val_score
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, confusion_matrix
import pickle
import requests
import json
import seaborn as sns

# Reading the train.csv by removing the last column since it's an empty column
DATA_PATH = "D:/Diabetdeck-V3/flask-server/dataset/Training.csv"
data = pd.read_csv(DATA_PATH).dropna(axis = 1)

# Checking whether the dataset is balanced or not
disease_counts = data["prognosis"].value_counts()
temp_df = pd.DataFrame({
"Disease": disease_counts.index,
"Counts": disease_counts.values
})

plt.figure(figsize = (18,8))
sns.barplot(x = "Disease", y = "Counts", data = temp_df)
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.show()

# Encoding the target value into numerical value using LabelEncoder
encoder = LabelEncoder()
data["prognosis"] = encoder.fit_transform(data["prognosis"])

X = data.iloc[:,:-1]
y = data.iloc[:, -1]
X_training_data, X_testing_data, y_training_data, y_testing_data =train_test_split(
X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 24)

print(f"Train: {X_training_data.shape}, {y_training_data.shape}")
print(f"Test: {X_testing_data.shape}, {y_testing_data.shape}")

# Defining scoring metric for k-fold cross validation
def cv_scoring(estimator, X, y):
return accuracy_score(y, estimator.predict(X))

# Initializing Models
models = {
"SVC":SVC(),
"Logistic Regression":LogisticRegression(),
"Random Forest":RandomForestClassifier(random_state=18)
}

# Producing cross validation score for the models
for model_name in models:
model = models[model_name]
scores = cross_val_score(model, X, y, cv = 10,
                         n_jobs = -1,
                         scoring = cv_scoring)

print("=="*30)
print(model_name)
print(f"Scores: {scores}")
print(f"Mean Score: {np.mean(scores)}")

# Training and testing SVM Classifier
svm_model = SVC()
svm_model.fit(X_training_data, y_training_data)
preds = svm_model.predict(X_testing_data)
# pickle.dump(svm_model, open('model.pkl','wb'))

print(f"Accuracy on train data by SVM Classifier\
: {accuracy_score(y_training_data, 
svm_model.predict(X_training_data))*100}")

print(f"Accuracy on test data by SVM Classifier\
: {accuracy_score(y_testing_data, preds)*100}")
cf_matrix = confusion_matrix(y_testing_data, preds)
plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
sns.heatmap(cf_matrix, annot=True)
plt.title("Confusion Matrix for SVM Classifier on Test Data")
plt.show()

# Training and testing Logistic Regression
lr_model = LogisticRegression(C=0.1, penalty='l2', 
solver='liblinear')
lr_model.fit(X_training_data, y_training_data)
lr_model.score(X_training_data, y_training_data)
preds = lr_model.predict(X_testing_data)
# pickle.dump(lr_model, open('model.pkl','wb'))

print(f"Accuracy on train data by Logistic Regression\
: {accuracy_score(y_training_data, 
lr_model.predict(X_training_data))*100}")

print(f"Accuracy on test data by Logistic Regression\
: {accuracy_score(y_testing_data, preds)*100}")
cf_matrix = confusion_matrix(y_testing_data, preds)
plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
sns.heatmap(cf_matrix, annot=True)
plt.title("Confusion Matrix for Logistic Regression on Test Data")
plt.show()

# Training and testing Random Forest Classifier
rf_model = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=18)
rf_model.fit(X_training_data, y_training_data)
preds = rf_model.predict(X_testing_data)
# pickle.dump(rf_model, open('model.pkl','wb'))

print(f"Accuracy on train data by Random Forest Classifier\
: {accuracy_score(y_training_data, 
rf_model.predict(X_training_data))*100}")

print(f"Accuracy on test data by Random Forest Classifier\
: {accuracy_score(y_testing_data, preds)*100}")

cf_matrix = confusion_matrix(y_testing_data, preds)
plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
sns.heatmap(cf_matrix, annot=True)
plt.title("Confusion Matrix for Random Forest Classifier on Test Data")
plt.show()

# Training the models on whole data
final_svm_model = SVC()
final_lr_model = LogisticRegression()
final_rf_model = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=18)
final_svm_model.fit(X, y)
pickle.dump(final_svm_model, open('D:/Diabetdeck-V3/flask-server/Model/save/svm/finalsvmmodel.h5', 'wb'))
final_lr_model.fit(X, y)
pickle.dump(final_lr_model, open('D:/Diabetdeck-V3/flask-server/Model/save/lr/finallrmodel.h5', 'wb'))
final_rf_model.fit(X, y)
pickle.dump(final_rf_model, open('D:/Diabetdeck-V3/flask-server/Model/save/rf/finalrfmodel.h5', 'wb'))

# Reading the test data
test_data = pd.read_csv("D:/Diabetdeck-V3/flask-server/dataset/Testing.csv").dropna(axis=1)

test_X = test_data.iloc[:, :-1]
test_Y = encoder.transform(test_data.iloc[:, -1])

# Making prediction by take mode of predictions made by all the classifiers
svm_preds = final_svm_model.predict(test_X)
lr_preds = final_lr_model.predict(test_X)
rf_preds = final_rf_model.predict(test_X)

final_preds = [mode([i,j,k])[0][0] for i,j,
           k in zip(svm_preds, lr_preds, rf_preds)]

print(f"Accuracy on Test dataset by the combined model\
: {accuracy_score(test_Y, final_preds)*100}")

cf_matrix = confusion_matrix(test_Y, final_preds)
plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))

sns.heatmap(cf_matrix, annot = True)
plt.title("Confusion Matrix for Combined Model on Test Dataset")
plt.show()

symptoms = X.columns.values

# Creating a symptom index dictionary to encode the input symptoms into numerical form
symptom_index = {}
for index, value in enumerate(symptoms):
symptom = " ".join([i.capitalize() for i in value.split("_")])
symptom_index[symptom] = index

data_dict = {
"symptom_index":symptom_index,
"predictions_classes":encoder.classes_
}
pickle.dump(data_dict, open('D:/Diabetdeck-V3/flask-server/Model/save/data_dictionary/datadictionary.h5', 'wb'))
```

> Link to dataset [here](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/kaushil268/disease-prediction-using-machine-learning)

> Below is a screenshot of the accuracy
> [image: Screenshot of accuracy and output]

Answer (score 1):

That you have 100% train and test accuracy probably means that your model is massively overfitting because of your amount of data.

But in general you should avoid overfitting as well as underfitting because both damage your performance of machine learning algorithms.

Comment: Hi if there's an overfitting happening how can I avoid that?

Comment: Steps for reducing overfitting: Add more data, Use data augmentation, Use architectures that generalize well, Add regularization (mostly dropout, L1/L2 regularization are also possible), Reduce architecture complexity.

Answer (score 0):

overfitting occurs in your code I think !

Answer (score 0):

This is not necessarily an error and this wouldn't be the first time someone acquired %100 accuracy on such a dataset either.*

Still, I would recommend using both training and test sets instead of using training.csv only. Have a look at [this example](https://www.kaggle.com/code/zoalfkarelhossin/data-mining-project/notebook) to see how there is actually two standard splits given as a part of the benchmark dataset.

```
train_df = pd.read_csv('/kaggle/input/disease-prediction-using-machine-learning/Training.csv')
test_df = pd.read_csv('/kaggle/input/disease-prediction-using-machine-learning/Testing.csv')
```

---

- Judging by the [other](https://www.kaggle.com/code/zoalfkarelhossin/data-mining-project/notebook) [attempts](https://www.kaggle.com/code/danushkumarv/disease-prediction-decision-tree) of training a classifier for the given dataset

Comment: I see. But if there's an overfitting happening how can I avoid that?

Comment: This hypothetical question should be asked in [another entry](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266767/what-is-the-the-best-way-to-ask-follow-up-questions).